# Inconsistent C++ <random> behavior between different computers

Tags: c++, random, simulation, probability

I've implemented a C++ solution for testing various strategies in reaction to the series of random events. I'm aggregating results from multi-threaded simulations running on a couple of computers.

A single simulation yields one integer outcome and typically requires generating around 100 uniform random integers and is repeated 1,000,000 times before a chunk of aggregated data (mean, standard deviation, minimum, maximum) is saved. Although, the results of such chunks are consistent up to 6 significant digits on a given architecture, the discrepancies between two computers running exactly the same program are orders of magnitude larger.

So far, I ran the program (the same executable) on two personal Windows notebooks with Intel processors and one AWS c3.8xlarge Windows Server instance. On each computer the ongoing simulation quickly approaches a different value. The relative discrepancies between means are of the order of 10^-3. On a single computer, the relative difference of means between 1-million chunks rarely exceeds 10^-6.

The program uses the `mt19937` random number generator from `<random>`. I use `time(NULL)` for seeding.

I can't come up with a reason for such an inconsistency. The Mersenne Twister is considered a sound generator for Monte Carlo simulations and I used it many times, often being able to analytically verify the results. I can understand slight differences and diversions from uniformity due to generator imperfections and underlying architecture but with such order of magnitude, it's hard to comprehend.

Comment: Not knowing how you are using the randomness, nor how exactly you are measuring the discrepancies (is that 10e-3 figure relative or absolute?) we can only guess. Did you try saving the seed used on one machine, and try to reproduce it in another? Could it be that on your notebooks you have directx calls changing the floating point flags behind your back? Do you seed the PRNG only once at the program startup, or more than once?

Comment: Baffles me why you tagged this C++ question as [tag:c]

Comment: I provided relative discrepancies. I seed PRNG just once.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong tag.

Comment: I'm not sure in what cases could such DirectX calls happen. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that; so, did you try with a fixed seed? If you can't reproduce the results, the source of the discrepancy is coming from outside the PRNG.

Comment: @Alethes: search for `D3DCREATE_FPU_PRESERVE` to see the horror for yourself.

Comment: Are your threads sharing the same instance of the PRNG? As I recall mt19937 has a very large amount of state in order to guarantee no cycles in some astronomical number of iterations.  If you are sharing the same instance that right there is a source of non-determinism.

Comment: Have you tried hardcoding the seed and running it on each of the three computers?  You can check whether the series of pseudo-random numbers are the same, if so (as expected) then you know the issue is with floating-point errors accumulating differently across the hosts, and nothing to do with random numbers at all.

Comment: Right, I'll check this out and let you know.

Comment: As for the threads, I'm using the same PRNG instance. However, with one thread it's just the same.

Comment: First 20 numbers for seed = 1 are identical. DirectX is not involved. The discrepancy is the same when running on a single thread. But how can floating-point errors yield such differences on very similar, 64-bit platforms?

Comment: It's eg. 106068.87 vs. 106357.32

Comment: @alethus can you edit the question with updates?  Use simplest case: fixed (identical) seed and single thread.  For a next investigation, determine where your simulations diverge.  The very first point of divergence.  A fear I would have would be use of 80 bit float registers or something: the divergence could be really early, and from that we can get a http://sscce.org

Comment: My thoughts are similar to Yakk's... 80 bit registers vs 64 memory storage can make subtle changes in a program, compiler, optimisation settings etc. produce different results, but you do say you're running the same executable.  You do mean the exact same code... no platform-specific compilations of shared libraries doing the number crunching...?  Also - be careful to find the point where the numbers diverge - not just their printed default/limited-precision stringified versions.

Answer (score 1):

After refactoring the program and eliminating unnecessary operations, the results became consistent among different hosts. It appears as though rounding errors significantly differ among various, seemingly similar, 64-bit architectures and their accumulation, due to certain design flaws, caused a serious divergence of my simulation's results. I'd like to thank @DanielKO, @TonyD, @amdn and @Yakk for their valuable suggestions.

An interesting note: from the very start, the c3.8xlarge AWS instance consistently provided the same (correct) results. In contrary, Core 2 took the most severe beating.

Comment: In theory if the compiler is set to strict IEEE 754 conformance mode FP operations should work the same way on any compiler... Are you sure you didn't enable some "unsafe" optimizations (like `-ffast-math` on gcc)?

Comment: The program was compiled with /O2 and /MT in Visual Studio 2013. I haven't used any custom settings and limited myself to the standard library. The code was compiled once, on my Core 2 notebook, and tested on another Intel notebook as well as the AWS' c3.8xlarge instance. All of them delivered different results and only the latter was correct all the time.

Comment: Perhaps lack of support for `long double` (other than mapping to `double`) took it's toll.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you have been able to fix your problem. Let me nevertheless point you to one or two (possible) problems with your code. Without actually seeing any sourccode it is hard to do more for you.

- Do *not* use `time(NULL)` as your seed. It is a very low entropy source - which is rather bad. First, two instances of the program running on different machines might very well pick the same seed and second, two consecutive runs will only have slightly different seeds, which might result in similar or at least correlated random numbers. This second point is especially bad if you create one prng per thread (as it is adviceable to do!) because then all threads might simply create identical numbers. Use at least a `seed_seq`, but better yet even a truly random source (`random_device`).
- While the standard guarantees, that the generator `mt19937` will give the same results in its 32 bit variant and (significantly) faster 64 variant, as well as across different hardware and software versions, the distributions do *not* give you the same guarantee. If you want to reproduce identical results, you should write your own distributions (which is IMHO a really bad design flaw of the standard as it is highly non-trivial to write a good distribution... this should not be necessary in your case though, as long as you only need randomly distributed numbers and never need to recreate a specific sequence of numbers).

While it is (as I already said) unlikely that the difference in distributions caused your problem, this is the only difference there can be between two standard-conforming implementations. In light of this, I would suggest checking the rest of your code thoroughly, as it seems unlikely that the `<random>` library is actually at fault here.

Comment: See also this talk: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful

Comment: Oh and I hope you are running with highest warning levels when doing numerics - or actually when doing anything. I have no idea about the VC flags, but in gcc every program can be written to compile without warning even with "-Wall -pedantic -Wextra -Wconversion -Wshadow", so why not use them?